# Why does value of j not change?

Tags: c

In the following code why does the value of j remains zero even after the statement j=i+10.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int i = 10, j = 0;
 if (i || (j=i+10))
   printf("%d",j);// j=0
}
```

Comment: C does [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Something you should have know if you read a book or two.

Comment: I don't write `c`, but is it because you're using a logical OR operator, and if `i` evaluates to `true` then the `j=i+10` wouldn't get evaluated?

Comment: Find out yourself. That's what debuggers are for!

Answer (score 4):

*Why does value of j not change?* Because `i` is `non-zero` and `logical OR (||)` properties is that if `1st` operand is true don't check `2nd` operand.

```
if ( i    ||  (j=i+10))
     |           |             
    10(True)   not evaluated
```

Comment: ISO9899:1990 is not C standard since ca. 19 years now. Please don't cite outdated versions of standards, unless a question asks for them.